# Statistical summary records in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, statistics

I have a dataframe (players_all) with game by game statistics on each NBA player, roughly of the form below

```
            Name   Date  Pts  Ast
0  Anthony Davis  10/22   25    5
1  Anthony Davis  10/25   21    2
2  Anthony Davis  10/27   29    3
```

I'd like to create a summary of statistics, one record per player, such as this:

```
            Name  Avg_Pts  MinPts  MaxPts  StDevPts
0  Anthony Davis     25.0      21      29       3.3
1     Trae Young     27.9       9      49       6.8
```

I supposed I could iterate through player_all by name, create a dataframe at each iteration, pull the statistic I want separately, output into a list, transpose and append all, but I'm guessing there's an easier way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'player' :['A','A','A','B'] ,'Pts':  [25,21,9,55],'Ast': [5,2,3,4]})

df = df.assign(avg_pts = df['Pts'],min_pts =df['Pts'] ,max_pts=df['Pts'] ,std_pts=df['Pts'] )    

df.groupby(['player']).agg({'avg_pts':'mean' , 'min_pts':'min','max_pts':'max' ,'std_pts': lambda x : np.std(x) })
```